# Bigquery Select all latest partitions from a wildcard set of tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group

We have a set of Google BigQuery tables which are all distinguished by a wildcard for technical reasons, for example `content_owner_asset_metadata_*`. These tables are updated daily, but at different times.

We need to select the latest partition from each table in the wildcard.

Right now we are using this query to build our derived tables:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `project.content_owner_asset_metadata_*`
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME = (
    SELECT
      MIN(time)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        MAX(_PARTITIONTIME) as time
      FROM
        `project.content_owner_asset_metadata_*`
      WHERE
        _PARTITIONTIME > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    )
  )
```

This statement finds out the date that all the up-to-date tables are guarenteed to have and selects that date's data, however I need a filter that selects the data from the maximum partition time of each table. I know that I'd need to use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` with `_PARTITIONTIME`, but cannot quite work out how to make a select work without just loading all our data (very costly) and using a standard greatest-n-per-group solution.

We cannot just union a bunch of static tables, as our dataset ingestion is liable to change and the scripts we build need to be able to accomodate.

Comment: for your interest: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36955074

Comment: This is where I would usually go about programmatically building the query. How many tables you have? And will it be fine if you get the data from them, for their most recent respective date partitions?

Comment: We have about 40 tables with close to 700 partitions each. We *want* to query against the most recent partition of each table, just not the other 699 in each table. The end goal is to build a looker derived table (basically a view) containing the latest data from each table.

Answer (score 1):

With BigQuery [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) (Beta now), there is a way to prune the partitions.

Basically, a scripting variable is defined to capture the dynamic part of a subquery. Then in subsequent query, scripting variable is used as a filter to prune the partitions to be scanned.

Below example uses BigQuery public dataset to demonstrate how to prune partition to only query and scan on latest day of data.

```sql
DECLARE max_date TIMESTAMP
  DEFAULT (SELECT  MAX(_PARTITIONTIME)  FROM `bigquery-public-data.sec_quarterly_financials.numbers`);

SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.sec_quarterly_financials.numbers`
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = max_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

With [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) (preview) as of posting, this can be achieved by joining to the PARTITIONS table as follows (e.g. with HOUR partitioning):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM `project.dataset.prefix_*` i
JOIN (
  SELECT * EXCEPT (r)
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table_name ORDER BY partition_id DESC) AS r
    FROM `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
    WHERE table_name LIKE "%prefix%"
      AND partition_id NOT IN ("__NULL__", "__UNPARTITIONED__"))
  WHERE r = 1) p
ON (FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d%H", i._PARTITIONTIME) = p.partition_id
     AND CONCAT("prefix_", i._TABLE_SUFFIX) = p.table_name)
```